# Evaluate and explain $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\arccos\left(\frac{\cos x}{\left(1+2\cos x\right)}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\arccos\left(\frac{\cos x}{1+2\cos x}\right)dx$$

I found this integral on a math discord server. I was unable to apply any standard integration technique to solve it (I am just an advanced high school student so my experience is limited). What methods can I apply to solve such an integral?

The expression does not seem to have an analytical solution.

[graph of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kge5b.png)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker know about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort tends to give the wrong impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: Discontinuous? Where? The only relevant range is $x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: This is known as [Coxeter's integral](https://youtu.be/1FixkRTDem0)

Comment: @K.defaoite. For the fun, have a look at my edit (using a 1,400 years old approximation !). Cheers and Happy New Year :-)

Comment: I've neutralized the downvote. Yes, we prefer people to show what they've tried with "seriously, I've seen these problems 100 times" questions, but **this** one is an infamous beast.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is Coxeter's integral.

Comment: I wouldn't vote for the closure for such a reason - having a reference *in the answer* is a good thing. But... the way *the question is asked*, and more generally the mass increase of *problem-statement-only* questions (tell me if I'm wrong), looks really disappointing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Just a welcoming gift to you and a New Year present.*

As you wrote, I do not think that an antiderivative exists. So, you are left with numerical integration or approximations.

The plot of the integrand is quite nice (looking more or less like a parabola). So, why not compose Taylor series and integrate termwise ?

Composing
$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{720}+O\left(x^{8}\right)$$
$$\frac{\cos (x)}{2 \cos (x)+1}=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{x^2}{18}-\frac{x^4}{72}-\frac{7 x^6}{2160}+O\left(x^{8}\right)$$
$$\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos (x)}{2 \cos (x)+1}\right)=\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+\frac{x^2}{12 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{23
   x^4}{1152 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{3727 x^6}{829440 \sqrt{2}}+O\left(x^{8}\right)$$

If you integrate termwise the above truncated series, you will get something $\sim 2.047$ while numerical integration would give $2.056$. Add as many terms as you can to improve accuracy.

**Edit**

What is amazing is that, using this $1,400$ years old approximation

$$\cos(x) \simeq\frac{\pi ^2-4x^2}{\pi ^2+x^2}\qquad \text{for} \qquad -\frac \pi 2 \leq x\leq\frac \pi 2$$ there is an antiderivative for
$$\int \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi ^2-4 x^2}{3 \pi ^2-7 x^2}\right)\,dx$$ The result is given in terms of an elliptic integral  of the first kind and a complete elliptic integral of the third kind.

For the integral, the result is
$$\frac{\pi}{84}   \left(21 \pi +20 \sqrt{3} \left(F\left(\csc
   ^{-1}\left( \sqrt{\frac{8}{3}}\right)|\frac{11}{6}\right)+\Pi
   \left(\frac{14}{9};-\csc ^{-1}\left(
   \sqrt{\frac{8}{3}}\right)|\frac{11}{6}\right)\right)\right)$$ which, numerically is $2.056016$ while numerical integration gives                 $2.056168$

Comment: The exact answer is $5\pi^2/24$; see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

As @K.defaoite notes, this is *Coxeter's integral*, equal to $5\pi^2/24$. The usual way (see *Inside Interesting Integrals* Secs. 6.2 and 6.3, where this takes Nahin just over **11** pages) to evaluate it (whose details I've half-provided as they're worth working through to appreciate how hard this is!) is to prove it's four times *Ahmed's integral* $A(1)$ where $A(u):=\int_0^1\tfrac{\arctan\left(u\sqrt{2+x^2}\right)}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{2+x^2}}dx$, so$$A(\infty)=\left[\tfrac{\pi}{2}\arctan\tfrac{x}{\sqrt{2+x^2}}\right]_0^1=\tfrac{\pi^2}{12}$$and$$A^\prime=\tfrac{1}{1+u^2}\left[\arctan x-\tfrac{u}{\sqrt{1+2u^2}}\arctan\tfrac{xu}{\sqrt{1+2u^2}}\right]_0^1$$so$$A(\infty)-A(1)=\tfrac{\pi^2}{16}-\int_1^\infty\tfrac{u}{(1+u^2)\sqrt{1+2u^2}}\arctan\tfrac{u}{\sqrt{1+2u^2}}du.$$With $u\mapsto1/u$, this simplifies to$$A(\infty)-A(1)=\tfrac{\pi^2}{16}-A(\infty)+A(1)\implies A(1)=\tfrac{5\pi^2}{96}.$$Now call your integral $C$ so, with some trigonometric identities,$$C=\int_0^{\pi/2}2\arctan\sqrt{\tfrac{1+\cos x}{1+3\cos x}}dx\stackrel{y=\tfrac{x}{2}}{=}4\int_0^{\pi/4}\arctan\tfrac{\cos y}{\sqrt{2-3\sin^2y}}dy.$$Since $\arctan b=\int_0^1\tfrac{bdt}{1+b^2t^2}$,$$C=\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^1\tfrac{4\cos y\sqrt{2-3\sin^2y}}{t^2+2-(t^2+3)\sin^2y}dtdy.$$With $\sin y=\sqrt{\tfrac23}\sin w$ followed by $s=\tan w$ (who'd guess *that*?),$$C=\int_0^{\sqrt{3}}\int_0^1\tfrac{8\sqrt{3}dtds}{(1+s^2)(t^2s^2+3t^2+6)},$$which simplifies by partial fractions to$$C=\tfrac{2\pi^2}{9}-4\int_0^1\tfrac{t\arctan\tfrac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+2}}}{(t^2+3)\sqrt{t^2+2}}dt.$$With $u=\arctan\tfrac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+2}}$, this becomes $C=4A(1)$, as desired.

Comment: This is a (nice) monster ! Thanks for posting it.