# $\int_{0}^{\frac{π}2} \arccos(\frac{\cos x}{1+2\cos x})dx=?$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was thinking to solve some difficult integration problems and I came across this. This is too hard for me to do. I began to solve this as usual but I couldn't find a way to proceed. Please help and thanks in advance. $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \arccos\left(\frac{\cos x}{1+2\cos x}\right)dx=?$$

Comment: Do you know how to do the Ahmed's integral?

Comment: Actually i don't

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~josephbreen/Some_Very_Challenging_Calculus_Problems-2.pdf see this

Comment: the question you are asking is of UCLA

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3966889/evaluate-and-explain-int-0-frac-pi2-arccos-left-frac-cos-x-left1  see this

Comment: This is a well known difficult integral called Coexter's integral which is also related to Ahmed's Integral.

Comment: This question was closed for being a duplicate of another question, but the linked question is also closed. Shouldn’t at least one of q’s be open?