# Integrating $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\arccos\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{1+2\cos(x)}\right)~\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Find the integral

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\arccos\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{1+2\cos(x)}\right)~\mathrm{d}x.$$

Been struggling on this one for ages.

Comment: You should post some of that struggle so we can help you in more detail.

Comment: Well, I tried making a substitution for the part in the brackets, but the result was something long and complicated

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597839/ would be a similar question. It is interesting to investigate the differences between these questions.

Comment: [This one's famous](https://youtu.be/1FixkRTDem0).

Comment: You may try $y=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{1-2\cos(x)}\right)$ to get rid of the inverse cosine

Comment: Numeric evaluation gives $5\pi^2/24$. Possible zeta function involvement.

Comment: Further to my previous comment, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3966988) is a concise summary of the "monster" calculation.